# redirect stderr to a buffer in c

Tags: c, posix, stderr

I have looked at the previous questions that have been asked. And I have come up with this code to obtain the current value of stderr, re-direct that to a buf and reassign stderr. This is code.

The redirect of the stderr to the buff is not happening. I can see this on the screen when I try to execute the code :

```
     ls: cannot access system: No such file or directory
     hellow world
     error from buffer
```

The source code looks like this :

```
#include<stdio.h>
static int fd;
static fpos_t pos;
char *buf;

void closeerr()
{
    fflush(stderr);
    fgetpos(stderr, &pos);
    fd = dup(fileno(stderr));
    buf =(char *)calloc(sizeof(char *),1024);
    stderr = fmemopen(buf, sizeof(buf), "w");
}

void reverterr()
{
    fflush(stderr);
    dup2(fd, fileno(stderr));
    close(fd);
    clearerr(stderr);
    fsetpos(stderr, &pos);
}

void main()
{
    closeerr();
    printf("hellow world");
    system(" ls -l system"); // this is where I see the error msg
    printf("error from buffer %s",buf);
    reverterr();
}
```

This code re-directs stdout(the logic would be the same to re-direct stderr) to a temp file ( Approach 1 as suggested below though I have not forked and created a child process to write into the file )

```
void switchStdout(const char *newStream)
{
  fflush(stdout);
  fgetpos(stdout, &pos);
  fd = dup(fileno(stdout));
  freopen(newStream, "w", stdout);
```

}

```
void revertStdout()
 {
  fflush(stdout);
  dup2(fd, fileno(stdout));
  close(fd);
  clearerr(stdout);
  fsetpos(stdout, &pos);
 }

void main(){
  switchStdout("/tmp/err.txt");
  printf("Hello world");
  revertStdout();
}
```

Comment: Given `char *buf;` what what do you think `sizeof( buf );` is?

Answer (score 1):

The `fmemopen()` function does not actually open a file descriptor, thus `fileno()` on a `FILE` obtained from `fmemopen()` returns an undefined value. `fmemopen()` is implemented by writing directly to the buffer without ever sending the data through the operating system. It is not possible to preserve the file opened with `fmemopen()` through a `fork()`.

Another problem is that you never allocate memory for your buffer, read about the `fmemopen()` API and how to use it to understand the problem.

Here are two approaches that work:

- open a temporary file, then `fork()`. In the forked process, dupe its file descriptor over file descriptor 2 (`STDERR_FILENO`) and then execute your command. In the parent, `wait()` for the child, then read what it wrote to the temporary file. Note that you need to do an `lseek()` before reading as the child will change the file pointer.
- open a fifo with `pipe()`, then `fork()`. In the child, dupe the writing end over file descriptor 2, close the reading end and then execute your command. In the parent, close the writing end and read what the child wrote from the reading end while its running. Don't forget to `wait()` for the child afterwards.

Comment: I considered the approach of writing the output to a temp file(read from the temp file and then into the buffer) instead of redirecting it to a buffer. It would be a slight overload and I would like to avoid doing it. This is shirt hand version of a larger problem and there may be many instances of the system call being made.

Comment: @bhavs you cannot avoid this, as when you redirect the STDERR file number correctly, all calls to `fprintf("stderr"` will go to your mem buffer anyway, but when you redefine stderr nothing happens for `write(2` calls.

Comment: @ikrabbe Yes, but in the child, only the file descriptor is preserved. `fmemopen()` does not create a file descriptor, so any approach that relies on `fmemopen()` is doomed from the beginning.

Comment: @bhavs Since the parent and child are different processes there is no way around going through the operating system. The overhead is not that large. If you are afraid of the file growing large, use approach two (pipe). With a pipe, the data never hits the disk. With approach one, it is only very likely that the data never hits the disk (provided you use `mkstemp()` to create it).

Comment: that's what I meant: You cannot use this simple solution, you have to go a more complex way.

Comment: Can I update this question with the other piece of code that I have written to open a temp file and write stderr data to this ? I had not thought about fork() a child process though when I wrote this code. Will you be able to provide comments for the same ? Would that be a part of the same question or will I have to raise another question at SO ?

Comment: @bhavs Go for it, but if the question becomes sufficiently different, better ask a new one.

Comment: @bhavs You can use the file based approach (approach 1) with the additional requirements as well, no problem.